# how to get jquery to recognize on change with a radio button

Tags: jquery, onchange

Is it possible to get jquery to regonize an onChange when a radio button is clicked?

I have the HTML markup:

```
<div class="wf__jqAPcontrol[1] wf__hide wf__optional" style="display: block;">
<label>Additional Info</label>
<fieldset class="wf__list wf__jqAPhtml" enabled="enabled">
<fieldset class="vf__list vf__jqAPhtml" enabled="enabled">
<label for="specialDiscount[1]_529663" style="padding: 0 !important">
<input type="checkbox" value="-5.00" name="specialDiscount[1]" id="specialDiscount[1]_529663" class="wf__list jq__recomputeThisService" checked="checked"> Discount (5%)
</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have this jquery code (which flows on page at bottom just before closing  tag):

```
<script>
    $('.jq__recomputeThisService').change(function() {
    ...
    }); // end .change()
</script>
```

Clicking the checkbox does not evoke the .change() function. Is it only possible with onclick()?

If so, how might I get the mouse button click action to call my .change() function?

Comment: where is the .change() function on the page?  Is your code being run inside a document.ready function?

Comment: Are you adding HTML dynamically?

Comment: yes I am @Satpal -- using an open source tool as well. That is why the markup looks like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are adding HTML dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

Example

```
$(document).on('change', '.jq__recomputeThisService', function() {

});
```

Comment: Thank you @Satpal. I will work with what you are sharing here and see if I can make it work.

Comment: AWESOME EXCELLENT FANTASTIC @Satpal. That you so much for helping. I had been spinning my wheels looking in the wrong place on this matter for about 3 hours. So greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name attribute to select it

```
$("input[name='specialDiscount[1]']").change(function() {

});
```

or if the name is created dynamically you could use

```
 $("input[name^='specialDiscount']").change(function() {

  });
```

Comment: I have a large block of code that I execute onchange. The onchange can be evoked from a select element, input element or a checkbox element. That is why I put `jq__recomputeThisService` on the class attribute. So How would I get all change events to call the same function @argonaut36?